# Merging overlapping dataframes in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

Okay, so I have two different data frames (df1 and df2) which, to simplify it, have an ID, a date, and the score on a test. In each data frame the person (ID) have taken the test on multiple dates. When looking between the two data frames, some of the people are listed in df1 but not in df2, and vice versa, but some are listed in both and they can overlap differently.

I want to combine all the data into one frame, but the tricky part is if any of the IDs and scores from df1 and df2 are within 7 days (I can do this with a subtracted dates column), I want to combine that row.

In essence, for every ID there will be one row with both scores written separately if taken within 7 days, and if not it will make two separate rows, one with score from df1 and one from df2 along with all the other scores that might not be listed in both.

EX:

**df1**

```
ID Date1(yyyymmdd) Score1
1  20140512        50
1  20140501        30
1  20140703        50
1  20140805        20
3  20140522        70
3  20140530        10
```

**df2**

```
ID Date2(yyyymmdd) Score2
1  20140530        40
1  20140622        20
1  20140702        10
1  20140820        60
2  20140522        30
2  20140530        80
```

**Wanted_df**

```
ID Date1(yyyymmdd) Score1 Date2(yyyymmdd) Score2
1  20140512        50                     
1  20140501        30
1  20140703        50     20140702        10
1  20140805        20
1                         20140530        40
1                         20140622        20
1                         20140820        60
3  20140522        70
3  20140530        10
2                         20140522        30
2                         20140530        80
```

Comment: Please show small example dataset and expected result based on that example

Comment: As you can see on the this line the test was taken within 7 days so it combined it into one line while the others were not so they were made in separate rows. I hope this example helps.

Comment: It's still not highly reproducible, but I don't think it deserves downvote

Comment: Is it safe to assume that there is at most one test 2 you want to join to every test1, and vice versa?  Or could someone take 2 test2s in the same week and you would want duplicate values of test1 for each of those.... since outer join seems out of the question I am wondering if there is a loop approach

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Yes, for every test1 there is at most one test 2 that could match up with it (the people took the one test every week at most so if i do <=6 there will be only one join per date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright.  I feel bad about the bogus outer join answer (which may be possible in a library I don't know about, but there are advantages to using RDBMS sometimes...) so here is a hacky workaround.  It assumes that all the joins will be at most one to one, which you've said is OK.

```
# ensure the date columns are date type
df1$Date1 <- as.Date(as.character(df1$Date1), format="%Y%m%d")
df2$Date2 <- as.Date(as.character(df2$Date2), format="%Y%m%d")

# ensure the dfs are sorted 
df1 <- df1[order(df1$ID, df1$Date1),]
df2 <- df2[order(df2$ID, df2$Date2),]

# initialize the output df3, which starts as everything from df1 and NA from df2
df3 <- cbind(df1,Date2=NA, Score2=NA)

library(plyr) #for rbind.fill

for (j in 1:nrow(df2)){
  # see if there are any rows of test1 you could join test2 to
  join_rows <- which(df3[,"ID"]==df2[j,"ID"] & abs(df3[,"Date1"]-df2[j,"Date2"])<7 )
  # if so, join it to the first one (see discussion)
  if(length(join_rows)>0){
    df3[min(join_rows),"Date2"] <- df2[j,"Date2"]
    df3[min(join_rows),"Score2"] <- df2[j,"Score2"]
  } # if not, add a new row of just the test2
  else df3 <- rbind.fill(df3,df2[j,])
}
df3 <- df3[order(df3$ID,df3$Date1,df3$Date2),]
row.names(df3)<-NULL # i hate these
df3  
#    ID      Date1 Score1      Date2 Score2
# 1   1 2014-05-01     30       <NA>     NA
# 2   1 2014-05-12     50       <NA>     NA
# 3   1 2014-07-03     50 2014-07-02     10
# 4   1 2014-08-05     20       <NA>     NA
# 5   1       <NA>     NA 2014-05-30     40
# 6   1       <NA>     NA 2014-06-22     20
# 7   1       <NA>     NA 2014-08-20     60
# 8   2       <NA>     NA 2014-05-22     30
# 9   2       <NA>     NA 2014-05-30     80
# 10  3 2014-05-22     70       <NA>     NA
# 11  3 2014-05-30     10       <NA>     NA
```

I couldn't get the rows in the same sort order as yours, but they look the same.

Short explanation: For each row in df2, see if there's a row in df1 you can "join" it to.  If not, stick it at the bottom of the table.  In the initialization and rbinding, you'll see some hacky ways of assigning blank rows or columns as placeholders.

Why this is a bad hacky workaround:  for large data sets, the rbinding of df3 to itself will consume more and more memory.  The loop is definitely not optimal and its search does not exploit the fact that the tables are sorted.  If by some chance the test *were* taken twice within a week, you would see some unexpected behavior (duplicates from df2, etc).

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working great so far, but the one question I have is that there are a few more variables in each data frame. Do I need to add them where you first created df3 or will it bind the rest of the rows automatically?

Comment: and then just add a new line of code under the "if" statement for every variable from df2 that I want to keep?

Comment: Yes and yes -- I couldn't figure out a simpler, hassle-free way to do it.  there's no such thing as `cbind.fill()` unfortunately (to `cbind` dfs of unequal length and fill rest with `NA`)

Answer (score 1):

Use an *outer join* with an absolute value limit on the date difference.  (A *outer join* B keeps all rows of A and B.)  For example:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.*, b.* from df1 a outer join df2 b on a.ID = b.ID and abs(a.Date1 - b.Date2) <=7")
```

Note that your date variables will have to be true dates.  If they are currently characters or integers, you need to do something like `df1$Date1 <- as.Date(as.character(df$Date1), format="%Y%M%D)` etc.

Comment: I've never used this function so Im a little confused as to where I enter my data and variables in that equation. Also, that date format change did not work (just changed all to NA).

Comment: It also said that RIGHT and FULL OUTER joins are not currently supported

Comment: Crap.  You are out of luck with basic `sqldf` then.  For an outer join on a custom merge (not a common key), you might take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926948/custom-merge-function-in-r) specifically the answer about GenomicRanges.